# Ember programatically pass data between components

Tags: javascript, video, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two ember components, one to show video card (`video-card`) and another to show video modal (`video-modal`) when playing the video. What I want to achieve in Ember is to be able to pass to the `video-modal` the `video` object the model should currently play. As for now I wasn't able somehow to bind the `video` object from the `video-card` to the `video-modal`.

**/components/video-card.js**

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        play: function(){
            // outputs video title when video thumbnail is clicked
            console.log(this.get('video').get('title')); 
            Ember.$('#video-modal').openModal();
        }
    }

});
```

The only thing these components have in common is the `/controller/application.js` controller because the components are inserted in different parts of the tempalte:

**/tempaltes/application.hbs**

```html
{{video-modal}}
```

**/templates/index.hbs**

```html
{{#each model.videos as |video|}}
<li>
  {{video-card video=video}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Ho to bind the `video` object from `video-card` when `play()` action is triggered, to the `video-modal` component dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog for this purpose. You can place the modal-dialog component inside your video-card component (or next to it in the loop) and have them share the property.

Comment: I'm not sure that rendering a modal dialog for each video would be a good option.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the goal. In that case you might want to pass the data up through an action.

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to do such a thing. long time ago I used this [Example](http://jsbin.com/tesepahako/edit?html,js,console,output). There is no need of a plugin to do such a simple task.